# what's the difference between tf.constant and tf.convert_to_tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

`tf.to_float(tf.convert_to_tensor(python_object))` used many times in Tensorflow object detection api like [grid_anchor_generator](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/cb1567e87cd92ab0394a0f7b0d5c1cb226a2cbde/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/grid_anchor_generator.py#L56-L65). normaly I'll use `tf.constant(python_object, dtype=tf.float32)`. I'm wondering the difference between them. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For `tf.constant`, the input value must be a static non-tensor type. For example a numpy array.

For `tf.convert_to_tensor`, the value "an object whose type has a registered Tensor conversion function." This means input types like Tensors or tf.Variables can also be provided as inputs. For example, see the tensor conversion function for Variables here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L762

Comment: Thanks, can you detail the scenario where Tensors or tf.Variable has to be converted to tensor with `tf.convert_to_tensor`

Comment: The key here is that it allows numpy arrays, Tensors, python lists, or python arrays as parameters. This means that if you want to write a helper graph construction function that takes any of these are a parameter, you can by simply calling `tf.convert_to_tensor`. Otherwise you would have to handle that conversion logic yourself in your code.

Comment: `tf.constant(tf.constant([0.0]))` runs perfectly fine on 2.4. `tf.constant(tf.Variable([0.0]))` does, however, error

Comment: What's the difference between tf.tensor and tf.constant?